# webclient cannot use file (being used by another process..)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

OK...part of this code MOST LIKELY makes busy the file I want and i need to release resources otherwise the file can't be used by webclient or anything else:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); 
string remote = "sample.jpg"; 
string px = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath.ToString(); 
if (File.Exists(px+"1.jpg") != true) 
{ 
    string local = px + "1.jpg"; 
    webClient.DownloadFile(remote, local); 
} 
else 
{ 
    string local = px + "2.jpg"; 
    webClient.DownloadFile(remote, local); 
} 
try
{
    byte A, R, G, B;
    Color pixelColor;
    Color pixelColor1;

    string rt = px + "1.jpg";
    string rt1 = px + "2.jpg";

    System.Drawing.Image a = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(rt);
    Bitmap bitmapImage = new Bitmap(a);

    System.Drawing.Image a1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(rt1);
    Bitmap bitmapImage1 = new Bitmap(a1);



    List<string> list = new List<string>();


    for (int y = 0; y < bitmapImage.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < bitmapImage.Width; x++)
        {
            pixelColor = bitmapImage.GetPixel(x, y);
            pixelColor1 = bitmapImage1.GetPixel(x, y);
```

I get this error.

> Line 168: webClient.DownloadFile(remote, local);" [IOException: The process cannot access the file

Comment: I dont really follow your question here.  You have a file in use by this code, but you can fix it with an override?  What do you need from us?

Comment: This is the error: "Line 168:                webClient.DownloadFile(remote, local);" [IOException: The process cannot access the file

Comment: which line is line 168?

Comment: @ paqogomez - thanks for the comment. no I meant i can fix the issue with complete code-rewriting. But I want simpler solution. Such as...how to dispose and what to release. My guess is that the graphics object "bitmapobject" is using the jpeg image "2.jpg" and i can't use it then in webclient? 10x again.

Comment: Here is the complete trace of the error as shown by asp.net:

Comment: Line 166:                Label1.Text += px + "2.jpg";
Line 167:                string local = px + "2.jpg"
Line 168:                webClient.DownloadFile(remote, local);
Line 169:            }
Line 170:

Comment: Your error is happening in code that you havent shown.  how to you declare and use the `remote` and `local` variables?

Comment: WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            string remote = "sample.jpg";
            string px = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath.ToString(); 
            if (File.Exists(px+"1.jpg") != true)
            {

                string local = px + "1.jpg";
                webClient.DownloadFile(remote, local);
            }
            else
            {
              
                string local = px + "2.jpg";
                webClient.DownloadFile(remote, local);
            }

            try
            {
                byte A, R, G, B;
                Color pixelColor;

...

Comment: what i just wrote above is the very beginning of the code. you can join the snippe right above with the code that i posted in my very first message. the error is yes in the code right above. Picture "2.jpg" is being used by another process. This process is most likely the code in the very first message.

Comment: I think your problem is here. `if (File.Exists(px+"1.jpg") != true)`.  Instead try `if (File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(px, "1.jpg")) != true)`

Comment: Do the same here `string local = System.IO.Path.Combine(px, "1.jpg");`

Comment: 10x - just tried it but same thing. I forgot to mention: The code works perfectly the first time. I mean..the code is wrapped in a timer control - the first time when a timer ticks everything works perfectly. But then obviously I am not closing some stream in the graphics object below which blocks the timer for any further success and on the second timer tick I am getting exception.

Comment: Also, what is the actual value of `Request.PhysicalApplicationPath.ToString();`?  Is this path native to the machine that you are running on?

Comment: you could also try disposing your webclient.  `webClient.Dispose();` after your if statement and before your try.

Comment: @Yes the path is 100% correct I already checked it while displaying in a Label control to be 100% sure that the part is pointing to existing/right files. Yes, you are right about disposing - i tried disposing the bitmapImage objects already and this "fixed" the issue. i am not getting errors anymore but they seem to destroy everything and the timer is displaying only the first result over and over again instead of showing intended/desired progress. But at least i am not getting errors now! thanks again - will keep posted here later.

Comment: I'll post an answer you can accept, if thats alright.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `webclient` is still hanging on to your file.

Try disposing the webclient so it releases its resources.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); 
string remote = "sample.jpg"; 
string px = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath.ToString(); 
if (File.Exists(px+"1.jpg") != true) 
{ 
    string local = px + "1.jpg"; 
    webClient.DownloadFile(remote, local); 
} 
else 
{ 
    string local = px + "2.jpg"; 
    webClient.DownloadFile(remote, local); 
} 
webClient.Dispose()
```

Comment: Yes, the issue indeed hidden in the disposing - but again it wasn't webclient but the graphics. Basically this seems to fix it:    bitmapImage.Dispose();
                bitmapImage1.Dispose();
                a.Dispose();
                a1.Dispose();

Comment: So disposing bitmapimage and "a" will release "2.jpg" for further use. I was wrong earlier that this destroys the object as the issue is actually my browser caching the first occurance of "2.jpg" and any repeated changed picture will not be detected. So i had to fix the browser image caching issue. I am 99% sure now that everything works but need to make 3-4 tests to see if everything in the algorithm is correct. Will write again in 30 minutes or so and will mark your answer as best.

Answer (score 1):

Know that it's pretty old, but try using block instead.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
   client.DownloadFile(remotePath, localPath);
}
```